# How can I convert a Unicode string to an AnsiString?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Trying to move project from Delphi 2007 to Delphi XE4. What is the best way to convert `String` to `AnsiString` in Delphi XE4?

Comment: I fixed all the various mis-references to XE4. It's important to take care with stuff like this.

Answer (score 15):

You simply assign it:

```
var
  AnsiStr: AnsiString;
  Str: string;
....
AnsiStr := Str;
```

The compiler will emit a warning mind you:

```
W1058 Implicit string cast with potential data loss from 'string' to 'AnsiString'
```

You can use a cast to suppress that warning:

```
AnsiStr := AnsiString(Str);
```

By default that gives no warning, although there is of course still potential for data loss. If you enable warning W1060 then the compiler says:

```
W1060 Explicit string cast with potential data loss from 'string' to 'AnsiString'
```

---

Of course, it's not expected that Delphi XE4 code has much place for the use of `AnsiString`. Unless you have a very specific interop requirement, then text is best held in the native data type, `string`. If you want to operate on byte arrays use `TBytes` or `TArray<Byte>`.

Comment: Lots of serial communication protocols uses AnsiString. Being able to handle this in a sensible manner requires careful planning, since AnsiString D2009+ is not equal to AnsiString in D2007.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by this comment. Did you mean "String D2009+ is not equal to String in D2007"? Because if you actually declare something as AnsiString in both, I believe you'd not have any problems. Or did they actually change something in AnsiString as well?

Comment: They actually changed AnsiString in D2007 to a slightly different AnsiString in D2009